# set method to PUT in rails XML requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, rack, middleware

if I do this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/xml' -d '<person>...</person>' 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/people/12?_method=PUT'
```

I get "Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed." Why? Rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a malfunctioning in rails recent versions. The solution is to pass the HTTP method override header with put. Important:the full name of the header is http-x-http-method-override but rails adds the http prefix so you should trim that part.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a specification on that Rails is broken? I thought the request body in this case was just a text chunk, like the BLOB when uploading a file, and should not be processed by the http parts of Rails. That Rails then detects the format and extracts the JSON to an object is nice, but hardly required by the HTTP spec?
So I'm a bit confused as to where Rails is malfunctioning in this case ...

Comment: Need link to rails Github commit :P

Answer (score 4):

luca is correct, you need to send the X-Http-Method-Override header with your request. Putting _method=put in the JSON body did not work for me. Your curl command line will look like this:

```
 curl
  -H "X-Http-Method-Override: put"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"blah@example.com\"}}"
  www.site.com/users/username.json
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that could be going wrong.

First off, you're sending a `POST` with `curl`, but you've got the "magic" `_method` parameter on your URL, and it's set to `PUT`. Based on the error, it sounds like Rails is taking `POST` as the authoritative request type. Try it without that and see what happens.

On a more pedestrian error, the routing (in `config/routes.rb` could be configured to not allow `POST` requests for for the action you are attempting to use.

If you're using a standard RESTful controller, that makes good sense, because you're accessing a member (`/people/12`) which by default only allows `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`.

I would try using `curl -X PUT` and dropping the `?_method=PUT` from your request.

Comment: you're right.. what I didn't mention is that while curl is capable of sending PUT requests, most browsers aren't and I'm writing in flex, which is not capable of it. Therefore I have to choose between GET and POST and try to make it understand it's a PUT...

Comment: Makes sense. Did you try lower case 'put' as your _method parameter? I looked at a form generated by Rails (update forms use PUT) and it used this code: `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />`.

Comment: What does  /people/12 have to do with REST?

Comment: Wahnfrieden, that's a standard format for Rails' RESTful routing. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html